# Can VSCode detect the git folder in a monorepo without dedicated tools?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am employed at a company that utilizes a monorepo approach without employing any dedicated tools. This means that within our GitHub repository, there is a main directory with a `.git` folder, along with several subfolders containing various Java applications. Additionally, there is one specific folder dedicated to the frontend application.

The structure of the repository resembles the following:

```
.git
foo-folder
  java-app
    ...
some-folder
  ...
  bar-folder
    docs
      ...
    frontend-app
      node_modules
      package.json 
      src
      tsconfig.json
      ...
    java-app-3
      ...  
  .....
```

When attempting to open the frontend application from its location, I noticed that vscode fails to recognize the presence of the git folder unless I open vscode from the root of the repository.

Is there a way to instruct vscode to navigate upwards until it finds the git folder? This would enable me to view modified files and make commits directly within vscode.

Comment: 1) weird that it's failing to notice it. Can you check that you haven't accidentally changed the `git.openRepositoryInParentFolders` to be `never`? The default value is `prompt`, and there's the option to set it to `always`. You can find some historical explanation of the setting here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/172010 2) what's the value of your `git.autoRepositoryDetection` setting?